# C Macro expansion into multiple function definitions

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have 3 very similar log functions that will be called from different places.

```
void INFO (char *format, ...) {
   char log_buf[256] = {0};
   va_list args;
   va_start(args, format);
   vsprintf(log_buf, format, args);
   va_end(args);
   LIB_LOG_INFO(log_buf);
}

void ERROR (char *format, ...) {
   char log_buf[256] = {0};
   va_list args;
   va_start(args, format);
   vsprintf(log_buf, format, args);
   va_end(args);
   LIB_LOG_ERROR(log_buf);
}

void DEBUG (char *format, ...) {
   char log_buf[256] = {0};
   va_list args;
   va_start(args, format);
   vsprintf(log_buf, format, args);
   va_end(args);
   LIB_LOG_DEBUG(log_buf);
}
```

I cannot pass any extra arguments, so I cannot do an if-else to call the different LIB_LOG functions.

Is it possible to write a generic macro that will expand into these 3 function definitions at compile time? Only the names of the LIB_LOG functions are different.

Comment: Use vsnprintf...

Comment: What have you tried? And I think you might want [the `##` (preprocessor token glue) operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace#.23_and_.23.23_operators).

Comment: Why don’t you simply use those functions?  They’re not that expensive. If you must, make them `static inline`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us how the using code will look like. That is the code that uses the macro(s).

Answer (score 2):

First of all please note that variable argument functions in particular are almost certainly the wrong solution to *any* problem. They are to be regarded as a deprecated, dangerous feature - avoid them if possible.

The being said, you can solve your problem by making a single generic function that takes a function pointer parameter:

```
typedef void lib_log_func_t (char* buf);

void lib_log (lib_log_func_t* func, const char* format, ...)
{
  char log_buf[256] = {0};
  va_list args;
  vsprintf(log_buf, format, args);
  va_end(args);
  func(log_buf);
}
```

Then write 3 wrapper macros:

```
#define INFO(format, ...)  lib_log(LIB_LOG_INFO,  format, __VA_ARGS__)
#define ERROR(format, ...) lib_log(LIB_LOG_ERROR, format, __VA_ARGS__)
#define DEBUG(format, ...) lib_log(LIB_LOG_DEBUG, format, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: I think the `func` parameter should be removed from the `define`'s parameters. By the way, about the `variable arguments are the wrong solutions` they are necessary if you want to make `printf` like functions. In particular, for this use case, GCC has a compiler attribute to check that the parameters passed to the function matches those required by the printf family: `__attribute_((__format__(__printf__)))`

Comment: @LoPiTaL Yeah of course, that was a typo - fixed, thanks. And no, we shouldn't be making printf-like functions. `stdio.h` in general should be avoided in production code - these are some of the worst designed functions in computer history, when looking back at the amount of bugs and damage caused by them.

Comment: The wrapper macros assume that `LIB_LOG_INFO` et al are functions and not function-like macros.  The all upper-case names suggest more macros — that may not be a safe assumption.

Comment: It would be better to use `vsnprintf()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "Only the names of the LIB_LOG _functions_ are different"

Comment: Yes — I've heard people think that macros were functions before.  I said "may not be a safe assumption" — that's all.

Comment: @Lundin *we shouldn't be making printf-like functions*  I have to disagree with you on that, at least until you can demonstrate another approach that will create usable logging functions that don't have to rely on application-level locking to ensure atomic writes to a log file.  `infoLogEntryWithTwoStringsOneIntOneUnsignedLongAndFourDoubles()` and all its required brethren isn't realistic, nor is forcing the caller to construct a string manually - the solution there will likely be `s[n]printf()` anyway.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Why exactly can't your log function - tasked with the job of writing a string to a log - take a string as function input?

Comment: @Lundin I'm guessing you missed my edit - because then the caller is just going to construct the string with `s[n]printf()`.  That's going to cause a lot of replicated effort likely to cause a lot of bugs that otherwise could be done in a well-tested and thoroughly-scrutinzed logging library function.

Comment: +1 for the function pointer solution, though.  Looks a lot like a logging library I wrote close to 20 years ago.  ;-)  The nice thing about a macro solution is you can add `__LINE__`, `__FILE__` and function name macros to the log entry easily.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Whenever I implement logging I do it as a separate module of the application. All your formatting needs should be placed in that log module.... and that's about it.